# Does it matter what indexes are named, i.e. if they're changed in a table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Background: Table has about 200m rows 55GB.

I need to do a row copy-over to a duplicate table but with a BIGINT identity and of course when generating the script to CREATE from original table it leaves everything the same, including the table name, INT value of the PK, and the PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT - all of which need to be changed.

My question is, if I change the PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT name, and don't change it back, will it screw things up?  Might stored procedures or direct commands call this constraint directly, as an index or something?  If it needs to be renamed later, is that an instantaneous process or a long one being such a large table?

I don't think it matters about the other indexes because I should just drop them on the original table before recreating on the new one, right?

And one more question:  On a table this size - and a high volume system, with performance in mind, should I be reconsidering changing any of the following values?:

```
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, 
    FILLFACTOR = 95
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index names are usually not directly referenced in programming API. There is no 'select from index' nor 'insert into index' syntax, everything references the table object. In few places though the index name is exposed, like for instance [table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).

But you may have in place administrative/maintenance scripts/jobs that are aware of the physical layout (ie. index and constraint names).

Comment: I'm guessing the process of searching an entire server for references to the index names would be impossible or impractical.  Would the recommended course then be to [1] create indexes on table_new with different names [2] take downtime [3] drop indexes on table_old [4] rename indexes on table_new to their original names and [5] switch out table names?  Would you put those steps in a different order?

Comment: I found that index names do not have to be unique, save for PKs.  So I was able to build them on the new table while the system was online.  And simply go offline quickly to copy the last fraction of data from the old table, drop its' PK, and rename the new table and its' PK.